# Cannot Convert String to char[] Error xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin

```
 string hello = "hello";


        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            CheckBox ch = new CheckBox(this);
            ch.SetText(hello);

            layout.AddView(ch);
        }
```

i saw few threads on stackoverflow where they were able to do the above step can't i do it in xamarin android?
    ch.SetText(hello);
i'm getting the error

Comment: should be able to use hello.ToCharArray()

Comment: What error do you get ? Do you expect us to guess or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the Text property

```
ch.Text = hello;
```